# Why are C++ unit tests failing with die program

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I have the following program written:
die.h

```
class Die {
    public:
        // Randomly assigns a value to roll_value in the range of 1 to 6
        void roll();
        // Returns roll_value
        int rolled_value() const;
    private:
        // Stores a randomly assigned value
        int roll_value;
        // Die sides, initialized to 6
        int sides = 6;
};
```

die.cpp

```
#include "die.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void Die::roll() {
   srand(time(0));
   roll_value = rand()%sides + 1;
}
int Die::rolled_value() const {
   return roll_value;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "die.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<windows.h>

using std::cout;

int main() {
  
   srand(time(0));
   Die die;
   int i = 0;
   for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
   {
       die.roll();
      Sleep(1000);
       cout << "Roll #"<< i << ", Roll Value: " << die.rolled_value() << "\n";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Roll #1, Roll Value: 4
Roll #2, Roll Value: 1
Roll #3, Roll Value: 4
Roll #4, Roll Value: 2
Roll #5, Roll Value: 5
Roll #6, Roll Value: 2
Roll #7, Roll Value: 5
Roll #8, Roll Value: 3
Roll #9, Roll Value: 6
Roll #10, Roll Value: 3
```

I'm testing with the following test:

```
TEST_CASE("Test that die returns a value between 1 and 6") {
    Die die;
    REQUIRE(die.rolled_value() > 0);
    REQUIRE(die.rolled_value() < 7);
}
```

And getting that this test is failing with the following message:

```
  REQUIRE( die.rolled_value() < 7 )
with expansion:
  11860256 (0xb4f920) < 7

===============================================================================
test cases: 2 | 1 passed | 1 failed
assertions: 3 | 2 passed | 1 failed
```

**I never have gotten a number greater than 7 when running this program but the test, testing for output greater than 7 is failing... Why is this happening?**

Comment: Call `srand(time(0));` only once, not each time you draw a number.

Comment: you ask for the rolled number before rolling the die

Comment: Judging by the test, you're supposed to set the rolled value in the constructor, not as a separate call to a member function.

Comment: okay, so in the Class Die constructor, roll_value should be: int roll_value = 0; and not int roll_value; Am I understanding correctly? @molbdnilo

Comment: Not in the constructor, no. You don't have any constructor yet. Read about them in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're experiencing undefined behavior. It is not legal to read a value before it's initialized.

Your test is showing something interesting: What should be the value of a die when you haven't rolled it yet?

Maybe you should have a zero value, or maybe the die should be rolled when constructed.

Comment: How would it look to code "rolling the die when constructed"? Setting "int roll_value = 1;" in the Class Die constructor in the die.h file did allow my tests to pass. But would it be better in terms of getting a random result on the first "roll" to roll the die when constructed? @guillaume

Comment: The program still seems to generate random results with int roll_value = 1; in the Class Die constructor. So I would assume there would be no problem

Comment: @Erin yes, but the first result is never random. The contructor would look like that: `Die() { roll(); }` or even better, make a function that returns a new random number, and use it for both initializing the first value and to roll the dice.